# Reaching Private Domain hosted in Route53 by using API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an EC2 instance in a private subnet, I reach it internally by using a private domain hosted on Route 53, now I want to use API Gateway and I tried 2 ways but return an error:

- I created a private RESET API and attach it to VPC Endpoint and allowed action from any resource in endpoint policy also in API I set resource policy to allow a principal to all resources but when invoking the API it returns "Network error communicating with endpoint"

Resource Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:me-south-1:Account-ID:API-ID/*/*/*"
    }
]}
```

VPC Endpoint policy:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Principal": "*"
    }
]}
```

- I created a regional API with Integration type "VPC Link" which is connected to NLB and when invoking API it returns "Internal server error"

the point I want to reach: Invoke API > internal API should be invoked and return a response